# Choosing a number between $1$ and $4$ before rolling three dice

Tags: probability, dice

> A player selects one number from $1$, $2$, $3$ or $4$ and rolls three standard dice. What is the probability that his chosen number appears on all three dice?

To answer this, I calculated the probability of the player choosing the number $1$, and then the number $1$ appearing on all three dice, and adding this to the probability of the player choosing the number $2$ and then the number $2$ appearing on all three dice, etc.

Probability of player choosing the number $1$, and then the number $1$ appearing on all three dice:

$$P(x=1)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}.$$

When multiplying this above probability by $4$ to get the answer, I got

$$P(X)=\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6},$$

which is the same probability as the case where the player didn't choose a number from $1$ to $4$ but from $1$ to $6$. Choosing a number from $1$ to $4$ and getting the chosen number three times obviously has a lower probability that choosing a number from $1$ to $6$ and getting the chosen number three times. What is the flaw in my logic?

Comment: Obviously? I'd not say so much as that...

Comment: No, there is no flaw in your logic. The answers are logically correct.

Comment: Doesn't matter which number you choose, the probability is the same for each.

Comment: But you're restricting yourself to one of four numbers coming out as success as opposed to one of six! How is that intuitive?

Comment: Just think about one die.  If I choose $1$, I have a $\frac 16$ shot at winning.  Same if I choose $2$, or any other value.  Makes no difference what you choose or how you make your choice.

Comment: Your $P(X=1)$ is a **conditional probability**. Let $Y$ the random variable for the chosen number.Then the **correct notation** is $P(X=1|Y=1)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6}$

Comment: Here's another way to build intuition:  suppose I could choose any of the six numbers and I chose $1$, whereas you could only choose between $1-4$ and you also chose $1$.  Do you suppose that then we have different chances of winning?